How to handle failed to open a stream warning (Cli.php) line 79; Magento local installation on Xampp; win11
I am trying to install Magento locally with Xampp on win11. I've tried to do the installation with composer, also trying different versions of magento package 2.4.6 (2.4.7 as well). I assumed that the problem I have may be related to the structure of the folders and file paths in the downloaded package. Each time, I was able to download the package itself, but could not proceed further with the installation. Here is what I did:

Downloaded Xampp 8.2.12 for Windows
Enabled extensions in php.ini: intl, sodium, socket, zip, gd, soap, xls
In Win11 adjusted System32 -> drivers -> etc -> host file
Created db named magento246
Got Adobe access keys, but haven’t been prompted to use them during package download so far
Got Composer 2.8.4 to download  magento
Magento community package (2.4.6) was downloaded successfully from magento repo as in the instruction:
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/composer
Got Elasticsearch 8.16.1

During the execution of php bin/magento setup:install,  Elasticsearch & Xampp (+Mysql) were enabled. I’ve also got admin privileges to magento folder files.
I had various issues during my attempts to install the previously downloaded package, but the latest issue and the first one during the install process now is the following:
gitBash screen of the warning /issue
Every command starting with php bin.. returns the warning that is actually blocking the installation. Here is what I've tried:
-reinstall vendor folder
-composer update (returned nothing to update)
-composer dump-autoload
Clearly, I am missing sth, maybe some basic. I wonder if the issue is related to the structure of the folders and paths as the warning indicates. I had a look at these path files, but nothing brought me closer to the solution. I’d appreciate any hints how to proceed?

Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve this. Is this a Composer issue, a Magento issue, or any issue related to [tag:localhost]?

Nico, thanks for your interest in my question. I finally managed to go with the installation. The problem was caused by incomplete access rights to some of the Magento files. In my case (win11), both admin and users had all privilages, but I had to grant the exact same privilages to the username as it is displayed in the command line. Previously, admin and users full access rights were not enough unless a particular user is part of a user group. It turned out to be so obvious. Thanks
